# Align text in toString

Tags: java, android, text, tostring, text-alignment

I want to keep the order as it is in this code, but I don't know how to make the value of degree under the value of university

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Education" +
                " " + System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                 year+ "        "+ university + System.getProperty("line.separator")+
                 "              "+ degree ;
    }
```

what I want

```
2023     UniversityExample 
         Bachelor of somthing
```

but appears like this :

```
2023     UniversityExample     
   Bachelor of somthing
```

or like this :

```
2019 to 2023     UniversityExample 
                       Bachelor of somthing
```

Comment: Err, tabs? But this is the wrong place to do this kind of thing. `toString()` is intended for debugging and to have unspecified output format.

Comment: Are there other method to get recyclerView from activity to itext pdf document?  @user207421

Answer (score 0):

You can use \t in the method, something like this

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    
    return "Education" +
            "\t" + System.getProperty("line.separator") +
            year+ "\t"+ university + System.getProperty("line.separator")+
            "\t"+ degree ;
    
}
```

Comment: it's has already arranged the code but not as I want, Thank you.

Comment: okay, what exactly do you want? from the question it looks like you just want proper formatting, is it something else you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *[String#formatted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...))* method to create a fixed-width string.

The full list of format specifiers can be found on the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* *JavaDoc* page.

```java
return
    "Education%n".formatted()
  + "%-17s%s%n".formatted(year, university)
  + "%17s%s".formatted("", degree);
```

Here are some example outputs,

```
Education
2023             UniversityExample
                 Bachelor of somthing
```

```
Education
2019 to 2023     UniversityExample
                 Bachelor of somthing
```

Comment: thank you, but this give me an error..